# Telerik Data access cant add new table or update any table

Tags: asp.net, telerik-open-access

I got this error when i want to update the database from Telerik data access designer.
Anyone face this problem before?

[click the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q8pr.png)

[My ig_mt_workflow database relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaRBZ.png)

Comment: From the look of it, it looks like a mismatch foreign key constraint. Check to see if your database tables that references 'ig_mt_workflow' uses the correct foreign key constraint/s.

Comment: please see the link that i reattached. the relationship is look like ok.